# How to edit jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm not very experienced in Javascript/jQuery/CSS3 animations.

I needed an animated slider, so I downloaded an [example](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/) from internet and tried to modify it.

At that banner image were at right side and texts were at left side.
But, I need image at left side and texts at right side. 
That's why, I change the image's `div` and text's css this way:

Previous CSS code:

```
.da-img {
   position: absolute;
   left: 60%;
}
.da-slide p, .da-slide h2, .da-slide a {
   position: absolute;
   left: 10%;
}
```

After changed by me:

```
.da-img {
   position: absolute;
   left: 10%;
}
.da-slide p, .da-slide h2, .da-slide a {
   position: absolute;
   left: 40%;
}
```

After changing it, it worked fine: 
[image]
 But, when slider goes to the left to right or right to left, every things go to their previous position: 
[image] 
I don't understand why it happened. Every time after refreshing page, the image shows at the left side of the `div` for the first time, but after the slider moves, everything changes!

Please, tell me how can I fix it. You can see my touched files [here](http://abidhasan.zxq.net/ParallaxContentSlider/).

Comment: did you adjust the `@keyframes fromRightAnim1` to the right position? so it works with your animation style?

Comment: No, I can't understand how I adjust it :(

Comment: Here's a decent tutorial to CSS3 animations: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand better how key frames works go [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/) and have a read about it. they way he explains stuff is just really good.

there is some stuff you need to play with before you can make it work: this here is your start state:

```
.da-slide-fromleft h2{
    -webkit-animation: fromLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -moz-animation: fromLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -o-animation: fromLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -ms-animation: fromLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    animation: fromLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
}
```

the rest is in sample at css/style.css line #337 as the name suggest is what happens when it does slide from the left side. that animation respond to this key frame:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fromLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fromLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
}
```

that is just like saying move my element from `-110%` to `10%` and while you do it change its opacity to 1.
what you need to do is see if there is any existing key frame that meets what you need, other wise just copy one of them change the name and play with the positions(right or left) and the `%`

so it will looks something like this::

```
.da-slide-fromleft h2{
    -webkit-animation: your_custom_name 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -moz-animation: your_custom_name 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -o-animation: your_custom_name 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -ms-animation: your_custom_name 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    animation: your_custom_name 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
}
```

and is key frame:

```
@-webkit-keyframes your_custom_name{
    0%{ left: -10%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 110%; opacity: 1; }
}
```

also you can play to make it better with the animation transitions and times, `easy-in`, `easy-out`, and so on.. more here :[CLICK ME](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/):

Comment: With respect to you, I'm telling that I haven't any knowledge of modifying javascript/css3 animation.It's tough for me to understand your urls and points.I thought just 1 or 2 lines code at js can fix those.But,now I'm realizing that it's complex for me.If I delete all the css for animation,everything is placed at my chosen place without any animation.But, at ie7, still they're opposite of my chosen direction.So,I can't handle this.Can you please give me a url of another content slider at where I need not complex modification? I need slider for this content: http://i.imgur.com/RutfmRw.png

Comment: @user1896653 I will help you more tomorrow.. :)